# Rational number that contains the sequence "$0123456789$"

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $n$ be a rational number that contains the sequence "$0123456789$" in its decimal representation.
Prove or disprove that there are
$p,q \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n = \frac{p}{q}$ 
and $q$ is a factor of $81$.

 For example:
\begin{align}
p &= 182 \\
q &= 5265 = 65 \cdot 81\\
n &= \frac{182}{5265}= 0.0345679\textbf{0123456789}79278851272738393
\end{align}

Comment: Do you mean that the sequence only exist for only one time?

Comment: Do you mean multiple but not factor?

Comment: The statement you're looking for is not true, and you can show this via a counter-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have, for instance, $0.\overline{01234567899} = \frac{137\,174\,211}{11\,111\,111\,111}$, where the donominator has prime factorization
$$
11\,111\,111\,111 = 21\,649 \cdot 513\,239
$$
and is therefore not divisible by $81$. So $q$ is not necessarily divisiblle by $81$.

However, *any* rational number can be written as a fraction where the denominator is divisible by $81$: Take the rational number $\frac pq$, and write it as $\frac{81p}{81q}$.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean $q$ is a multiple of $81$?

Then $0.0123456789=\cfrac {123456789}{10^{10}}$ but I can always multiply this by $\cfrac {81}{81}$ to get a fraction which is not in its lowest terms.